# Can there be a feature that redirects an off-topic question to the appropriate Stack Exchange site?

Tags: feature-request, migration, new-users, off-topic, migration-path-request

## Background

I was on Stack Exchange today, asking a regular ol' question, the gist of which was:

> What library do you use to make GUI-based apps in Java?

I asked it based on how apps that have used those libraries fared historically. Now, I understand that it was my fault for not reading the help center manuals and asking a question that was off-topic. However, almost immediately, my question began to get downvoted and in less than 10 minutes it was deleted.

### So What?

Now, I understand that this reflects Stack Exchange's hardcore policies for questions that don't serve their purpose on X website, but to a beginner user of Stack Exchange and a beginner in the world of technology in general, I feel quite upset and demotivated when such action is taken so abruptly. The reason I come to Stack Exchange is because I don't want to ask my questions on a more controversial platform like Reddit,  when I know that there exists a larger community of well-experienced developers who can help me.

Now, in light of that, my question was closed due to being 'off-topic', which is totally understandable. However, when I asked whether there was any place that could accept this question, I was replied to in the negative. So here is my feature request:

**Is it possible that when someone finds a question to be off-topic, they can request to have it redirected to the appropriate Stack Exchange  website? If not, then could a request be opened to potentially open a Stack Exchange website with the intent of addressing such issues if they appear in a large enough quantity?**

I understand that then a large number of user requests would then have to be processed for websites that would serve little to no purpose for the larger community at whole. In that case, could the question simply be marked as something like `Not A Valid Question` but still have users respond and answer to it so that at the very least an answer is reached? This type of question wouldn't affect the reputation of any respondent or asker or have its upvotes/downvotes affect its appearance on the website. Then perhaps you could warn the user about such a question in the future and direct them to the appropriate places to ask such a question should the need arise.

Thank You for reading this!

> **NOTE**: I added the off-topic tag because I am afraid that this may be off topic.

Comment: Were there any comments on your question that suggested the right site?

Comment: Question migration already exists (where a question is closed and moved to another site) and questions are migrated all the time. Subjective polls of the kind your asking are not a good fit for the SE model and wouldn’t be on-topic on any SE site though

Comment: What is a way to make a question not subjective @Cal?

Comment: It is the responsibility of the OP to determine an appropriate site for the question that only they have 100% understanding of, and is part and parcel of asking a question, not an auxiliary consideration that can be trivially outsourced..  Determination of the best site, (if there is a site), requires matching the question against the prospective target site rules/policy, and offloading of that effort onto another SE user tends to backfire against that user and/or the site providing the recommendation:(

Comment: @EnergyNumbers No

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such a feature already exists.

Users with 3k reputation who can cast close votes on questions can choose to migrate the question to another site:

> [image]

If five users vote to migrate, the question is migrated automatically. Otherwise, moderator can also do it, and migration can be requested via a custom flag on the question.

Comment: I'm reading the question as migration to *any site* and you're only addressing 1/3 of the question ...

Comment: Alright then, but what about if no appropriate website is found? When I asked over at my question, they replied that no website was able to accept my question.

Comment: @MansoorAhmad so I'm afraid you better find a different, non-SE site. As last resort you can post a [tag:site-recommendation] question here, but it's not a sure way to get what you want.

Comment: @rene that's the 1/3 that can be answered, and that is asked both in title and bold part of the question body.